# Would "some" be correct here?

Tags: grammar

I have some doubts about the use of "uncountable nouns" here. I know we use "some" with them because using an article is not correct, but when we say something general, is "some" required or correct?

Like in this example: Which is correct or are both?

> 1) Some British wine is sweet.

or

> 2) British wine is sweet.

I think the 2nd one is right, because the 1st one seems unnatural. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but mean different things.

"Some British wine is sweet" implies that "Not all British wine is sweet", and so "Some British wine is dry".

But "British wine is sweet" implies that "All British wine is sweet".

This is true for both countable and non-count nouns.  The word "some" changes the meaning.

(It's not relevant to the grammar, but be aware that "British wine" is horrible stuff made from dried grapes. It used to be drunk as a medicine it is virtually undrinkable. On the other hand "English wine" is proper wine made from local grapes and can be very high quality.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation :) I got it now :)